# Метод remove для массива

Tags: массивы, структуры-данных

Создаю улучшенную версию массива, если это так можно назвать.
Есть класс `Array`, в нем есть массив, который будет хранить данные, базовые методы, такие как `add`, `indexOf`, `get`, `set`, etc. Я хочу реализовать метод `remove` для удаления элемента по индексу. Массив имеет статический размер: если изначально был 10 элементов - 10 останется навсегда. Есть например массив ["A","B","C","D","F"]. Вызываю метод `remove` для 2 элемента("С"). Метод должен просто на место "С" поставить null(будет массив ["A","B",null,"D","F"]) или должен сместить элементы, а null в конец(["A","B","D","F", null]). Или есть третий вариант?

Comment: А если у вас в массиве `["Какой-то очень длинный текст в каждой ячейке", ...]` вы же понимаете, что вы будете работать со ссылками, а не с самими элементами? Какой из двух ваших методов будет эффективнее будет зависеть от того, чаще массив будет меняться или читаться. При частом чтении выгоднее "сжать" массив. При частой записи выгоднее не "сжимать", а писать `null` по месту. Ещё надо принять во внимание какой длины максимум будет массив. Если у вас будет массив на миллион элементов и вы часто будете из него удалять элементы, его "сжатие" может выйти в изрядный расход ресурсов.

Comment: Но можно "сжатие" делать не сразу, а периодически. Насколько я понимаю, обычно делают что-то гибридное - выделяют сплошной блок памяти, как-то с ним работают, а потом при необходимости через какое-то время его реорганизуют, когда он становится слишком фрагментированным, например.

Comment: Согласен с CrazyElf. Но для примера, функция `erase` в `std::vector` как раз использует 2 вариант. [ссылка](https://code.woboq.org/llvm/libcxx/include/vector.html#_ZNSt3__16vectorIbT_E5eraseENS_14__bit_iteratorINS0_IbS1_EELb1EXLi0EEEE)

Answer (score -1):

Третий и, на мой взгляд, самый правильный вариант для статического массива -- создать его копию без удалённого элемента. Если удалять "С", то просто вернуть ["A","B","D","F"] без null.